# How to close opened excels in python

Tags: python

Hi I have searched everywhere to close existing excel i got many codes from internet but in every code need to open excel, what my doubt is it poosible to close excel without giving open path in python

Comment: open using with statement it will automatically  close when you go out from the stateent

Comment: "close excel without giving open path in python" Wait, do you mean close *the Excel program*? Or close a file that someone else opened? Or close a file that you opened?

Comment: close a file that someone else opened

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
# Close EXCEL files to start fresh
import psutil

for openProcess in psutil.process_iter():
    #print("check") #Check all the on going process
    if openProcess.name() == "EXCEL.EXE":
        openProcess.kill()
print("All EXCEL closed")
```

This will kill all your excel files without saving the progress, no warnings.

Regards.